# Binding multiple contextmenu to table rows with jquery ui contextmenu

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, contextmenu

I have been working on a table with multiple context menus and different menus options, but it has been a mess to figure out how to bind every one to their proper selector.

I am using this plugin https://github.com/mar10/jquery-ui-contextmenu.

**DOM:**

```
<table id="contextMenu">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="hasCategory">
      <td>Category Name</td>
      <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="hasMedia">
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td colspan="2">Media name</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="hasFormat">
      <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
      <td>Format name</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**The javascript:**

```
jQuery(document).contextmenu({
    delegate: ".hasCategory",
    menu: [
        {
            title: "<i class=\"fa fa-file-o\"></i> New Category", cmd: "newcategory", uiIcon: "newCategory"
        },
        {
            title: "<i class=\"fa fa-trash-o\"></i> Delete Categoru", cmd: "deletecategory", uiIcon: "deleteCategory"
        }
    ]
});

jQuery(document).contextmenu({
    delegate: ".hasMedia",
    menu: [
        {
            title: "<i class=\"fa fa-file-o\"></i> Novo Formato", cmd: "newformat", uiIcon: "newFormat"
        },
        {
            title: "<i class=\"fa fa-trash-o\"></i> Excluir Media", cmd: "deletemedia", uiIcon: "deleteMedia"
        }
    ],
    select: function(event, ui) {
        alert("select " + ui.cmd + " on " + ui.target.text());
    }
});

jQuery(document).contextmenu({
    delegate: ".hasFormat",
    menu: [
        {
            title: "<i class=\"fa fa-files-o\"></i> Duplicate Format", cmd: "duplicateformat", uiIcon: "duplicateFormat"
        },
        {
            title: "<i class=\"fa fa-trash-o\"></i> Delete Format", cmd: "deleteformat", uiIcon: "deleteFormat"
        }
    ]
});
```

But it happens to work only for "**.hasFormat**" selector.

The documentation says to use document when setting multiple selectors, but its not working.

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery UI widget framework (that the context-menu) is based on, take care that only one instance of a plugin is bound to the same DOM element.

If you you want to have different menus for the table you could create 3 menus at different containers (e.g. document, body, and table element) that each contain the desired target elements. But I would *not* reccommend that in your case.

A better approach would be to create like this

```
$("#contextMenu").contextmenu({
    delegate: "tr.hasMedia,tr.hasFormat", // or simply "tr"
    menu: [],
    beforeOpen: function(event, ui) {
        // replace the whole menu depending on click target type
        if( ui.target.closest(".hasMedia").length !== 0 ) {
            $("#contextMenu").contextmenu("replaceMenu", [
                {title: "aaa"}, {title: "bbb"}, 
                ...
             ]);
        } else if( ui.target.closest(".hasFormat").length !== 0 ) {
            $("#contextMenu").contextmenu("replaceMenu", [
                {title: "aaa"}, {title: "bbb"}, 
                ...
             ]);
        }
    },
    select: function(event, ui) {
        alert("select " + ui.cmd + " on " + ui.target.text());
    }
});
```

(Often it may be enough to define only one menu, and use `enableEntry` and `showEntry()` to tweak it according to the target type.)